# How to prevent the csv file name to be the sheet name in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filenames

I'm new to python and would really appreciate some assistance. I exported the SSMS query to pandas data frame using Jupyter Notebook and then exported the data frame to csv. I need to run this python script every month so I am looking for the monthly csv file to be saved in a certain format i.e. CSV file name + Previous Month Name & Year eg: CSV File Name February 2022 when the python script is run in March 2022.

The problem is the Sheet Name of that CSV file shows CSV File Name along with Month Name and Year and I would like the Sheet Name to remain as "Sheet1" and not change every month when the python script is run i.e.  when I run the script in April 2022 I do not want the Sheet Name to become CSV File Name March 2022 and instead remain as "Sheet1"

Here's my code:

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from datetime import date 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
last_month = date.today() - relativedelta(months=1)  
text_date = format(last_month, '%B %Y')
server = 'server_name'
database = 'database_name'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER= {SQL Server};\
                   SERVER=' + server + '; \
                   DATABASE=' + database + ';\
                   Trusted_Connection = yes;')
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query("""Select * from Table""", cnxn)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_csv(r'filepath \filename' + str(text_date) + '.csv',  index = False)
```

Kindly help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Where/when are you seeing the 'sheet' name?

Comment: Indeed, CSV files do not contain sheets or sheet names, just the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have sheet_name option with df.to_csv, try using df.to_excel

df.to_excel(filename, sheet_name="sheet_name", index=False)

Comment: Yeah works fine with excel but need to figure a way out to do it in csv. Any other way of naming the csv file (in terms of coding) that could resolve it? Or any other way of exporting (instead of using pandas) to csv could help? Any libraries that could assist?

Comment: When I open the csv file I see the sheet name as the csv file name along with month name and year

Comment: @user18501174 There is no direct way of achieving this as excel organises data into sheets unlike CSV which is a simple file type and is not divided and/or arranged into multiple sheets, you may convert in into excel first if you have to have a particular sheet name.